ImportError: zstd C API versions mismatch when initializing ChromaDB via Langchain
I am facing the following error when trying to initialize a ChromaDB vector store via Langchain:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\nicol\onedrive\documents\uni\masterarbeit\giz\code\unstructured_preprocessing\semi-structured-rag_exmpl.py:335
    vectorstore = Chroma(collection_name="summaries", embedding_function=OpenAIEmbeddings())

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\langchain_community\vectorstores\chroma.py:120 in __init__
    self._client = chromadb.Client(_client_settings)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\chromadb\__init__.py:35 in Client
    return system.get_api()

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\chromadb\config.py:97 in get_api
    self.api = self._instantiate("chroma_api_impl")

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\chromadb\config.py:87 in _instantiate
    impl = cls(self)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\chromadb\api\local.py:57 in __init__
    self._db = system.get_db()

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\chromadb\config.py:92 in get_db
    self.db = self._instantiate("chroma_db_impl")

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\chromadb\config.py:85 in _instantiate
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126 in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1050 in _gcd_import

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1027 in _find_and_load

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006 in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:688 in _load_unlocked

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:883 in exec_module

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241 in _call_with_frames_removed

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\chromadb\db\duckdb.py:4
    from chromadb.db.clickhouse import (

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\chromadb\db\clickhouse.py:15
    import clickhouse_connect

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\clickhouse_connect\__init__.py:1
    from clickhouse_connect.driver import create_client

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\clickhouse_connect\driver\__init__.py:9
    from clickhouse_connect.driver.httpclient import HttpClient

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\clickhouse_connect\driver\httpclient.py:21
    from clickhouse_connect.driver.compression import available_compression

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\clickhouse_connect\driver\compression.py:7
    import zstandard

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\unstructured\lib\site-packages\zstandard\__init__.py:39
    from .backend_c import *  # type: ignore

ImportError: zstd C API versions mismatch; Python bindings were not compiled/linked against expected zstd version (10409 returned by the lib, 10505 hardcoded in zstd headers, 10505 hardcoded in the cext)

I was mainly following the instructions from this
tutorial notebook for a RAG application.
I am working in a conda environment with python 3.10. Would be great to hear if anybody did face this kind of error before.
Cheers!


10409 returned by the lib

This means it is picking up the lib file (on Windows this should be zstd.dll) with 1.4.9 which does not match the version 1.5.5 for the other components. Without knowing the specifics of your environment (except that it is Linux), you can try to track down the exact file(s) using ldd (and remove/update whatever that is outdated):
$ ldd backend_c.cpython-39-aarch64-linux-gnu.so
    ...
    libzstd.so.1 => /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zstandard/./../../../libzstd.so.1 (0x0000ffffb72c0000).
    ...

References:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=277784
https://github.com/conda/conda-libmamba-solver/issues/241
